# Proof of the feature of the function

Tags: functions

There is a continuous function for which $\ f(256)-f(2) = 7$. Prove that there is x for which $\ f(x^2) = f(x) + 1$

My intuition is:
$\ f(2^8) = f(2)+7$

which suggests:
$\ f(x^n) = f(x) + (n-1)$

However, I have no idea, how can I prove such a condition. Could you help and give some hints: what should be done in such a case?

Comment: Something is amiss. Consider $f(x)=c$ where $c$ is a constant. Can you provide the source of the problem?

Comment: Something strange since your intuition $f(2^8)=f(2)+7$ is in contradiction with the question $f(2^8)-f(2)=0$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the condition was meant to be $$f(256)-f(2)=7$$

In that case:  define $$g(x)=f(x^2)-f(x)$$

Clearly $$g(1)=0$$  We remark that $$g(2)=f(2^2)-f(2)\quad \quad g(2^2)=f(2^4)-f(2^2)\quad \quad g(2^4)=f(2^8)-f(2^4)$$
Suppose all three of those values were $≤1$.  Then we could add them together to get $$f(2^8)-f(2)≤3$$

But, that contradicts the given information (assuming my interpretation was correct).  Thus at least one of those terms is $>1$.  But then continuity tells us there must be some solution to $g(c)=1$ between $1$ and $2^4$ and we are done.

Comment: Therefore, if I am going to check a specified condition for f(a)(*)f(b) (I assign operation on these pairs of values as (*)), I have to choose a function g(x) which "inherits" this relation?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  I introduced $g(x)$ because the conclusion appeared to involve it, and I thought it might help, which it did.  I don't know that there's any sort of grand theory behind it.

Comment: OK, I understand that there is *no grand theory* - I am just looking for some hints or ways to analyse questions. However, I don't understand the last two sentences, especially the last one. Particularly, I don't understand how it relates to the question *Prove there is x for which...*.

Comment: Which two sentences?  From my proof you mean?  The logic of my proof is: I use the given assumption to show that at least one of $g(2), g(4), g(16)$ is $>1$  I don't know which, but I don't care.  It's clear that $g(1)=0$ so that means that, between $x=1$ and $x=16$, $g(x)$ is sometimes $<1$ and sometimes $>1$.  But then the Intermediate Value Theorem says that this implies $g(x)=1$ somewhere between $x=1$ and $x=16$.  That's what you asked.

Comment: Why do you choose >1?

Comment: So I could use the Intermediate Value Theorem.  I can't show that any of $g(2),g(4),g(16)$ are equal to $1$, but I can show that at least one is $>1$.

Comment: I understand the intuition of the theorem. However, I am still quite confused *why* one. Is it because we added one to the given function f(x^2)=f(x)+1?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I need $1$ because that's what you asked about.  Obviously, $g(c)=1$ is the same as $f(c^2)-f(c)=1$ which is the same as $f(c^2)=f(c)+1$, which, again, is what you asked about.   Note:  a simple modification of my argument shows that there is a $c$ such that $f(c^2)=f(c)+2$.  Perhaps it would help your insight if you tried to write that argument out.

Comment: Thank you, I think that now I see it :)